# Toolbar with AppCompatPreferenceActivity AND PreferenceHeaders

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-preferences

I'd like to use a `Toolbar` on my Settings activity, which is using `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`.  There's plenty of stuff online for doing this if you're just using `PreferenceScreen`, but I haven't found anything that *also* works with `PreferenceHeaders`.  Here's my current code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }
}
```

I also have some unremarkable `PreferenceHeaders` in an XML file, which have corresponding `PreferenceFragments`.  The activity runs fine, I just can't figure out how to get the toolbar in there.

Most of the stuff I've seen on this usually involves just a single `PreferenceScreen`, and you create a layout with the toolbar and a placeholder `ListView`, and load the `Preferences` into there, but that doesn't work for me.

I also tried `getSupportActionBar()`, but that returns null.

Anyone know how I can do this?  Thanks!

Comment: You have to first do `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)`.

Comment: @AlphaQ Yeah, I've tried inflating/creating my own `Toolbar` and using `setSupportActionBar()`, but no luck with that either.